# what does the network parameter mean or do in /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, debian, interface

I've seen following configuration that gives me a bit of a headache

```
    iface ens192 inet static
    address 10.27.202.21
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.2.0.0
    broadcast 10.27.0.255
    gateway 10.27.202.1
    dns-nameservers 10.27.2.3
    dns-search my.local.lan
```

I understand all basic parameters like broadcast, netmask, gateway,.. but its hard to find any information about the "network" parameter and on how to interpret it.

For me this seems a little bit wrong, but it works somehow.

Why is this "network" parameter not used in all static configs? (debian documentation) Can I simply ignore it?

I am using a debian 10 system.

Comment: These are pure network basics. Maybe try to learn, and there's no IPv6 here, can be added as well.

Comment: hi, ive tried specific search terms .. but the parameter "network" is so generic, its hard to find anything. usually im not bad in searching the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network address is the 'base' address of the network.

It's not required in 2020 AFAIK. Give it a try without !

I think it's a copy of an old distro config.

This is this info you can find in the output of [ipcalc](/questions/tagged/ipcalc), juste after the line `=>`

[image]

Comment: do i need this? because i saw configurations where this parameter does not exist, .. so whats the "meaning" behind this in terms of the configuration?

Comment: If you search for `ǹetwork` parameter in `man interfaces ` of a recent distro (like debian10), it's even not documented, because the network is easy to find for the OS with the IP/cidr or IP/mask. It's a not needed parameter by default

Comment: Ok thank you, will try. Now this makes sense to me!